# OpenCL1.2 AMD-APP Catastrophic error on compile under Linux

Tags: opencl

I am getting the following error when building OpenCL with the AMD-APP SDK on Ubuntu:

```
Compilation failed: 
"/tmp/OCLDUTgN7.cl", line 8: catastrophic error: cannot open source file
          "src//owOpenCLConstant.h"
  #include "src//owOpenCLConstant.h"
```

The `owOpenCLConstant` header file in question contains the following:

```
#ifndef OW_OPENCL_CONSTANT_H
#define OW_OPENCL_CONSTANT_H

#define MAX_NEIGHBOR_COUNT 32

#define MAX_MEMBRANES_INCLUDING_SAME_PARTICLE 7

#define LIQUID_PARTICLE 1
#define ELASTIC_PARTICLE 2
#define BOUNDARY_PARTICLE 3

#define NO_PARTICLE_ID -1
#define NO_CELL_ID -1
#define NO_DISTANCE -1.0f

#define QUEUE_EACH_KERNEL 1

#define INTEL_OPENCL_DEBUG 0

#endif // #ifndef OW_OPENCL_CONSTANT_H
```

This works with the Intel OpenCL1.1 SDK so it seems a bit strange. Is it an AMD-specific problem or could it be an OpenCL1.1 vs 1.2 thing?

I don't know much about OpenCL and haven't been able to find this error anywhere, if anyone can spot the problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What does your include statement look like? Based on the area looks like it can't locate or access the file at the given path.

Comment: the include statement looks like this: `#include "src//owOpenCLConstant.h"` - Why should the AMD builder fail to locate it and not the Intel one?

Comment: Really what I am after is your development setup. The reason is that your CL kernel is compiled at runtime (in your program). Your include, in your kernel, needs to be relative to your execution directory. Basically, when your program calls clBuildProgram your include needs to be relative to that directory. What is happening is that when openCL receives the build request it is looking for (current execution directory)/src/owOpenCLConstant.h which it can't locate.

Comment: Looks like AMD OpenCL compiler builds program in temporary directory. So the compiler cannot find the relative path for "src/owOpenCLConstant.h" file. You might need to specify extra `-I` option for `clBuildProgram()`. Or you can use the environment `AMD_OCL_BUILD_OPTIONS_APPEND` to append `-I` option to your existing program.

Comment: I think you're right @jclin. For now I will put the header information in the file `.cl` itself, but in future I will add the `-I` option.